# images on django site from matplotlib

Tags: django, matplotlib

I am looking to have an entry form where you can enter in a server name and end up getting several png images displayed that are created from matpotlib.

I can create the form, and have the scripts written that create the image files. I am wondering what the best way to deal with the images are. Is there a way I can display the resulting png file to the browser but not save it to disk?

Want to avoid cluttering up a directory with the generated images after they are displayed the the browser. Should I just delete the image after its rendered?

Answer (score 1):

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
img.save(response, "PNG")
return response
```